# Viewscoped JSF and CDI bean

Tags: jsf, cdi, view-scope

I'm using Java EE 6 on JBoss EAP 6, and my JSF beans are annotated like this:
`@ManagedBean @ViewScoped` (both from `javax.faces.bean` package)

However, they are also CDI beans (default constructor, use of `@Inject`, `@PreDestroy` etc). I'm reading all the time that you can't mix these annotations (JSF and CDI), but it's apparently working fine: Injections are working, preDestroy is called on view change etc).

Am I missing something? What is the problem? Why not use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CDI `@Inject` works "everywhere" and thus also inside JSF `@ManagedBean`. The JSF counterpart `@ManagedProperty` works inside `@ManagedBean` only. You also can't `@Inject` a true JSF managed bean in any CDI managed bean (instead, it would be a CDI managed instance). Perhaps this is what you was reading about. General consensus, however, is indeed to preferably not mix them to avoid confusion among starters. [JSF utility library OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a CDI compatible [`@ViewScoped`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) for JSF 2.0/2.1.

The `@PreDestroy` is by the way **not** specific to CDI, neither is its counterpart `@PostConstruct`. They should work just fine in both CDI managed beans and JSF managed beans.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems I'm really confused about all these things...

So what I have is a JSF managed bean, rather than a CDI bean? Even if this bean meets all requirements do be a CDI bean documentation talks about (default constructor, not inner class etc)? If so, what the difference to a CDI bean? what are the drawbacks or what I can't do with this bean that I can do with a CDI bean?

Comment: You can't `@Inject` the JSF managed bean instance elsewhere. If you don't actually need it, then there's not really a drawback. But noted should be that JSF is slowly moving to CDI. Upcoming new JSF specific annotations like `@FlowScoped` are CDI-only. The JSF `@ManagedBean` facility will be deprecated in near future. Users are encouraged to move to CDI before it happens.