# Inject CDI bean into JSF @ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, view-scope

I have a problem with JSF, CDI project. I did a lot of research and I found that in CDI there is no `@ViewedScoped` annotation. I solving problem with ajax based page with dialog. I want to pass variable to dialog from datatable. For this purpose, I can't use `@RequestedScoped` bean because value is discard after end of request. Can anyone help me to solve it? I can't use `@SessionScoped` but it's a bad practice IMHO. Or maybe save only this one variable into session who knows. Can you guys give me any hints how to solve this problem elegantly?

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;    
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceBean implements Serializable {
...
```

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean {

@Inject
ServiceBean serviceBean;


@Postconstruct ...
```

Here is the error message:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean warDetailBean
```

Comment: Use either CDI beans or JSF beans. Do not unnecessarily think of mixing them,

Comment: "*I do a lot of research and I found that in CDI is not `@ViewedScoped` annotation.*" This was true only before Java EE 7. Java EE 7 (JSF 2.2) transparently supports a compatible view scope (from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`) in flavour of the JSF view scope (from `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First**, If you are attempting to use CDI, you need to activate it by putting a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` file in your application (note that this file can be empty), more informations about that file could be found in the [Weld - JSR-299 Reference Implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/).

As you are using Tomcat, please be sure to respect all the configuration requirements by following the steps in [How to install CDI in Tomcat?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

**Second**, Even if you can use `@Inject` inside a JSF managed bean, It's preferable that you don't mix JSF managed beans and CDI, please see BalusC's detailed answer regarding [Viewscoped JSF and CDI bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18988938/4170582).

So if you want to work only with CDI `@Named` beans, you can use OmniFaces own CDI compatible `@ViewScoped`:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    ServiceBean serviceBean;
}
```

**Or**, if you want to work only with JSF managed beans, you can use `@ManagedProperty` to inject properties:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean{

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceBean}")
ServiceBean serviceBean;

}
```

### See also:

- [ManagedProperty in CDI @Named bean returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921324/managedproperty-in-cdi-named-bean-returns-null)
- [Omnifaces CDI ViewScoped](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped)

Comment: I ll give the OmniFaces one more chance cause when I add dependency to it, it generate errors. CDI is setup properly everything work fine. I just need @ViewScoped bean. Cause I have a lot of ajax on page.

Comment: @Milkmaid please see the showcase i think that  may help you: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Comment: OmniFaces said that I dont have CDI. But I have it in dependency with weld implementation. Do I need Application server cause I user Tomcat

Comment: did you added the WEB-INF/beans.xml file to your application?

Comment: Yes it is there all the time.

Comment: please follow how to configure CDI using tomcat from here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70920/discussion-between-milkmaid-and-tarik).

Comment: In JavaEE7 containers a `beans.xml` file is not necessary as CDI is active by default in EE7

Comment: @NBW True, but I said that he must add beans.xml because he is using Tomcat. Anyway, thanks for your exactness:)